# parsley lib is not showing validation messages on this wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parsley.js

```html
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST" data-parsley-validate="true" name="form-wizard">
    <div class="wizard-step-1">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="pull-left width-full">Search Slot </legend>
            <!-- begin row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group block1">
                        <label>Date *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="dtpSearch" id="dtpSearch" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control datepicker-autoClose1" data-parsley-group="wizard-step-1" required  />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Start Time *</label>
                        <div class="input-group date 24hourtime" >
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFromTime" name="txtFromTime" value="00:00 AM" placeholder="Enter StartTime" data-type="alphanum"  data-parsley-required="true" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>End Time</label>
                        <div class="input-group date 24hourtime" >
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtToTime" name="txtToTime" value="23:59 PM" placeholder="Enter EndTime" data-type="alphanum"  data-parsley-required="true" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Court Type</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="ddlCtype" name="ddlCtype" data-parsley-required="true">
                            <option value="">Any</option>
                            <option value="1">Concrete</option>
                            <option value="2">Clay</option>
                            <option value="3">Grass</option>
                            <option value="4">Sand</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Roofed *</label>
                    <div>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optRoofed" checked data-parsley-validate="false" value="0">No</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optRoofed" data-parsley-validate="false" value="1">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
    </fieldset>
</div>
<!-- end wizard step-1 -->
```

I am using this [lib](http://parsleyjs.org/) on this wizard. I have removed some of wizard step for sake of clarity. Now work fine on webapp other pages where i did not use this wizard. why it is not working on this wizard?? 
**Note:Skipping some wizard step for the sake of clarity.**